# Microsoft works 9.0

Tags: windows-7

My computer keeps telling me in won't support anything less than internet explorer 9, I have Windows 7 64 bit but it says to put in a cd because it cant just update. All I do on this thing is Google stuff for school,  read the news and check out ebay. Nothing big. The cd's are expensive. Do I really have to get them?

Comment: Your question is really hard to follow. What are you doing, and what exactly is happening?  What changed to cause this to start happening?  What have you attempted already to make it stop? How did you install Works originally if you don't have the CD's?  if you don't need it, why not uninstall Works?

Comment: What does Works have to do with IE? Unless the Works installer/program itself is asking you to update? If so, have you tried downloading IE9 from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home)?

Comment: i think "works" is just a verb - it's his poor english..

Comment: @DrStrangeLove: Maybe, or maybe s/he is *actually* referring to [MS Works 9.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Works#Works_for_Microsoft_Windows)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're talking about Microsoft Works, which no one in their right mind uses.
It sounds like you're fairly new to this.

Microsoft Office Home & Student is not very expensive. You can share it with 3 people, the CD Key is good for 3 computers.

http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116856&name=Business-Finance

thats 40$ if you share 3 ways.

You're going to need this program to work with documents that other people send you. If you want, you can download libreoffice instead, which is free, but less popular.

You'll want to delete "Microsoft Works" from the programs & features application in your control panel.

I also recommend you install the following with your new computer:

- Firefox
- VLC Media player
- Winrar
- Flash player
- fox it PDF

This should get you started to be able to open & work with your computer in  "basic" manner like you want.